# Diamond of death and Scope resolution operator (c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have this code (diamond problem):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Top
{
    void print() { cout << "Top::print()" << endl; }
};

struct Right : Top 
{
    void print() { cout << "Right::print()" << endl; }
};

struct Left : Top 
{
    void print() { cout << "Left::print()" << endl; }
};

struct Bottom: Right, Left{};

int main()
{
    Bottom b;
    b.Right::Top::print();
}
```

I want to call `print()` in `Top` class.

When I try to compile it I get error: `'Top' is an ambiguous base of 'Bottom'` on this line: `b.Right::Top::print();` 
Why is it ambiguous? I explicitly specified that I want `Top` from `Right` and not from `Left`.

I don't want to know HOW to do it, yes it can be done with references, virtual inheritance, etc. I just want to know why is `b.Right::Top::print();` ambiguous.

Comment: This is ambiguous by *"If a class member access operator, including an implicit “this->”, is used to access a non-static data member or non-static member function, the reference is ill-formed if the left operand (considered as a pointer in the “.” operator case) cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer to the naming class of the right operand"*, 11.2p6. Note that the naming class is `A`, but `D*` cannot be implicitly converterted to `A*`.

Comment: The semantics here are, that you tell it what function you want to call with the `B::A::tell`. You help the compiler with using `D::tell`, i.e with the name lookup. But you don't specify the subobject that it must use - it will have two choices: Going down the road to `A` over `B` or over `C`, and will give you the error.

Comment: There are two "major" ambiguity checks that are done in contexts that operate on objects at runtime: one in 5.2.5p5, and one that bite you here in 11.2p6. The one in 5.2.5p5 rejects `d.tell()` if you were to remove all tell functions except the one of `A`, as the naming class then is `D`, but `tell` would be a direct member of `A`, and `A` is ambiguous. If you then say `D.B::A::tell()`, it is well-formed by 5.2.5p5, but ill-formed by 11.2p6. These checks complement each other and are important for proper operating in the type system.

Comment: Here is a related question, where MSVC++ accepts aswell: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4130201/34509

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Why is it ambiguous? I explicitly specified that I want `Top` from `Right` and not from `Left`.

That was your intent, but that's not what actually happens. `Right::Top::print()` explicitly names the member function that you want to call, which is `&Top::print`. But it does not specify on which subobject of `b` we are calling that member function on. Your code is equivalent conceptually to:

```
auto print = &Bottom::Right::Top::print;  // ok
(b.*print)();                             // error
```

The part that selects `print` is unambiguous. It's the implicit conversion from `b` to `Top` that's ambiguous. You'd have to explicitly disambiguate which direction you're going in, by doing something like:

```
static_cast<Right&>(b).Top::print();
```

Comment: Then why it works if I use `Right::print()` instead of `Right::Top::print()`? Neither one works with pointer-to-member, but `b.Right::print()` will work. (of course I have removed `print()` in `Right` class).

Comment: @PcAF Because the conversion from `b` to `Right` is unambiguous. There's only one subobject of type `Right`.

Comment: Thank you for response. If conversion from `b` to `Right` is unambiguous, why this: `auto print = &Bottom::Right::print;` `(b.*print)()` gives `ambiguous base` error (Right is empty class)?

Comment: @PcAF That isn't ambiguous. Not with the hierarchy you posted.

Comment: In both comments I wrote that `print()` is removed

Comment: @PcAF regarding your follow-up comment. Using with `&Bottom::Right::print` is ambiguous because the type of that actually is `void(Top::*)()`. The information that you used `Bottom::Right` instead of `Bottom::Right::Top` is not remembered by the type system.

Answer (score 4):

The scope resolution operator is left-associative (though it doesn't allow parentheses).

So whereas you want to refer to `A::tell` inside `B`, the id-expression refers to `tell` inside `B::A`, which is simply `A`, which is ambiguous.

The workaround is to first cast to the unambiguous base `B`, then cast again to `A`.

Language-lawyering:

[basic.lookup.qual]/1 says,

> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the `::` scope resolution operator applied to a *nested-name-specifier* that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration.

The relevant grammar for *nested-name-specifier* is,

> *nested-name-specifier:*
>
> *type-name* `::`
>
> *nested-name-specifier* *identifier* `::`

So, the first *nested-name-specifier* is `B::` and `A` is looked up within it. Then `B::A` is a nested-name-specifier denoting `A` and `tell` is looked up within it.

Apparently MSVC accepts the example. Probably it has a nonstandard extension, to resolve ambiguity by backtracking through such specifiers.

Comment: Please cite the relevant standardese or else this is speculation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The [language-lawyer] tag was added after I posted. I'll see if I can whip up a good explanation, but note that it's simply impossible to do lookup from right to left.

Comment: @Potatoswatter +1, and see my comments to the question for references.

Comment: I encourage you to move your answer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36779466/34509 instead of on this duplicate-question

Answer (score 1):

Actually, giving code is working fine as I tried it on Visual Studio 2019.
There are two way to solve Diamond Problem;
 - Using Scope resolution operator
 - Inherit base class as virtual

Calling print function by `b.Right::Top::print()` should be executed with no errors. But there is still two objects of your base class (Top) referred from your Bottom class.

You can find additional detail in [here](http://www.tutorialdost.com/Cpp-Programming-Tutorial/50-CPP-Multipath-Inheritance-Ambiguity.aspx)